# Using XML::Simple to build XML from an array of hashes with some keys as attributes

Tags: xml, perl

I am using [`XML::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) and I wish to convert this data to XML:

```
@rooms = (
   {
      id => 4,
      is_key => 0,
      name => B507,
      capacity => 35
   },
   {
      id => 5,
      is_key => 1,
      name => B502,
      capacity => 24
   }
);
```

I want to output this:

```
<rooms>
   <room id=4 is_key=0>
      <name>B507</name>
      <capacity>35</capacity>
   </room>
   <room id=5 is_key=1>
      <name>B502</name>
      <capacity>24</capacity>
   </room>
</rooms>
```

I don't see a way to do this with `XML::Simple::XMLout`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find [`XML::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) unintuitive and very awkward to use. It is easy to end up just throwing random options at it to try to get it to work.

However if you are stuck with it there is a way. First of all the `ForceArray` option is very useful and, as the documentation says,

> Check out "ForceArray" because you'll almost certainly want to turn it on

So you need to adjust your data so that it looks like `ForceArray` was in effect when the original XML was parsed. This just involves putting in an anonymous array all data that should be the contents of an element instead of an attribute value.

This code does what you need. The `KeepRoot` option just tells `XMLout` that the top-level hash is the root element and it doesn't have to wrap the whole thing in another element.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my @rooms = (
   {
      id => 4,
      is_key => 0,
      name => 'B507',
      capacity => 35
   },
   {
      id => 5,
      is_key => 1,
      name => 'B502',
      capacity => 24
   }
);

for my $room (@rooms) {
  for my $k (keys %$room) {
      $room->{$k} = [ $room->{$k} ] unless grep $k eq $_, qw/ is_key id /;
  }
}

my $xml = {rooms => {room => \@rooms} };

print XMLout($xml, KeepRoot => 1);
```

**output**

```
<rooms>
  <room id="4" is_key="0">
    <name>B507</name>
    <capacity>35</capacity>
  </room>
  <room id="5" is_key="1">
    <name>B502</name>
    <capacity>24</capacity>
  </room>
</rooms>
```

---

**Update**

You may prefer a solution using [`XML::Smart`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSmart), which allows you to specify which nodes are elements and which are tags. This allows you to leave the original data in `@rooms` untouched.

This program accepts a similar hash reference to the `XML::Simple` solution, and them loops through all `/rooms/room` elements, setting all `name` and `capacity` child nodes to elements using `set_tag`.

Note that the XML is output using `scalar $smart->data()` because when called in list context
the `data` method will return a second value: a boolean flag indicating whether the XML is Unicode-encoded. This doesn't appear to be documented in the POD.

You may omit the call to `$smart->set_order` if you're not bothered about the order in which the attributes and elements appear in the XML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Smart;

my @rooms = (
   {
      id => 4,
      is_key => 0,
      name => 'B507',
      capacity => 35
   },
   {
      id => 5,
      is_key => 1,
      name => 'B502',
      capacity => 24
   }
);

my $smart = XML::Smart->new;
$smart->{rooms} = { room => \@rooms };

for my $room (@{$smart->{rooms}{room}}) {
  $room->set_order(qw/ id is_key name capacity /);
  $room->{name}->set_tag;
  $room->{capacity}->set_tag;
}

print scalar $smart->data(noheader => 1, nometagen => 1);
```

**output**

```
<rooms>
  <room id="4" is_key="0">
    <name>B507</name>
    <capacity>35</capacity>
  </room>
  <room id="5" is_key="1">
    <name>B502</name>
    <capacity>24</capacity>
  </room>
</rooms>
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the extra processing of the data, but short of writing a new XML Out procedure, that appears to be the best way. Thanks!

Comment: @hayesk: I have added a solution using `XML::Smart` which allows you to explicitly distinguish between XML attributes and elements. This avoids the additional processing of the source data.

Answer (score 2):

Hash value arrayrefs become XML element content, simple hash values become XML attribute values.

```
use strictures;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);

print XMLout(
    {
        room => [
            {
                id       => 4,
                is_key   => 0,
                name     => ['B507'],
                capacity => [35],
            },
            {
                id       => 5,
                is_key   => 1,
                name     => ['B502'],
                capacity => [24],
            }
        ]
    },
    KeyAttr  => [],
    RootName => 'rooms'
);
```

---

```
<rooms>
  <room id="4" is_key="0">
    <capacity>35</capacity>
    <name>B507</name>
  </room>
  <room id="5" is_key="1">
    <capacity>24</capacity>
    <name>B502</name>
  </room>
</rooms>
```

Answer (score 0):

Daxim's answer already is correct. Since I've typed it out I'll post this anyway. Here's a piece of code that will transfor your data structure into the one you need (which Daxim already pointed out).

```
my $stuff = { 
  'room' =>  [ 
    map { { 
      'id' => $_->{'id'}, 
      'is_key' => $_->{'is_key'}, 
      'name' => [ $_->{'name'} ], 
      'capacity' => [  $_->{'capacity'} ] 
    } } @rooms 
  ]
};

print XMLout($stuff, RootName=> 'rooms', );
```